# Can Report Viewer 2010 control be used in Visual studio 2008 without problems?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

Can Report Viewer 2010 control be used in Visual studio 2008 (ASP.NET apps) without problems? I saw [this post](http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2010/05/15/upgrading-to-report-viewer-2010.aspx) about it and wanted to know if this is supported and is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without problems? Doubtful :(
Google: reportviewer+2010+visual+studio+2008

Supposedly it can be done, and some resources exist:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changliw/archive/2010/06/29/use-the-reportviewer-2010-control-in-visual-studio-2008-project.aspx

However I've spent many hours this week trying and failed. The best I can get out of the control is a (hidden) HttpHandler registration error ("HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file").

Dunno, maybe I lack the mojo. I would love to hear from anyone who is using ReportViewer 2010, especially programmatically. Application configuration? Web.Config? etc..

HTH